# Pretty-Printing PyParsing Trees

Tags: python, parsing, pretty-print, pyparsing, parse-tree

Have anyone implemented pretty printing (preferrably using Python's builtin `pprint` module) of parse-trees outputted from PyParsing preferrably with indentation and alignment?

Comment: `pprint.pprint` pretty-prints dict, list, etc. The simplest way would be to transform your parse-tree into a list/dict structure. Is this possible?

Comment: Use `asList`: `results = parseString(s); pprint(results.asList())`. If you have defined any results names, you can use `asDict()`, or even just `dump()`.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire: Great! That does it for me for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use json for this.

```
import json
class PyParseEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, ParseResults):
            x = obj.asDict()
            if x.keys():
                obj = x
            else:
                x = obj.asList()
                if len(x) == 1:
                    obj = x[0]
                else:
                    obj = x 
        else:
            obj = super(PyParseEncoder, self).default(obj)
        return obj
```

And then

```
print json.dumps(parseresult, cls=PyParseEncoder, sort_keys=False, indent=2)
```

If you are getting error from json.dumps just add additional handler to encoder for specific data type.